# How to bind on the fly form elements with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Project Requirement is such that ,I have a form which contains dynamic form elements such as dropdown,radio buttons,input box,checkboxes.Please note that these elements sometimes come multiple times or single or none.
My question is how to bind this form with spring class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, these elements will be added to your form through some DOM manipulations.

In the case, just create some class which will represent form entity and will have all possible fields that you need and than expect it in your controller:

```
public void controllerMethod(FormDataObject formData){
  //logic
}
```

In your controller logic just check whether or not the data exist in the request payload.